# How to stop playing audio with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to stop audio playing, but not only pause it, but I also want if I reopen it, it starts at the first, not the middle that I stopped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access media controls through a jQuery object. As such you need to call the audio related methods on the Element object itself.

The use of `play()` and `pause()` is obvious, but to set the time index back to the start of the file you will need to use `currentTime`:

```
var audio = $('audio')[0]; // alternative: $('audio').get(0);

audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
```

Comment: Is it possible to write "audio.get(0).currentTime = 0;"

Comment: No, as given the example above `audio` is already an Element object, so `audio.get(0)` would raise an error

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

What did you already try ? This should do what you're looking for.

```
function stop(el){
    el.pause(); // Stop playing
    el.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
}
```

Here is a working example with an `id` specified instead of an `element`

```js
function stop(elementId) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  el.pause(); // Stop playing
  el.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/viola.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="stop('myAudio')">Stop playing</button>
```

Comment: Note that this won't work. jQuery does not have a `pause()` method or `currentTime()` property

Comment: Corrected @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Or just `el.pause()`